# Why was Kylo Ren wrong about Rey's lineage?

Tags: star-wars, character-motivation, the-last-jedi, kylo-ren, the-rise-of-skywalker

With the big reveal that

> Rey is Palpatine's grand-daughter

this whole bit Kylo Ren says [in *The Last Jedi*](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=star-wars-episode-viii-the-last-jedi) is definitely not true (slightly edited for brevity)

> Do you want to know the truth about your parents?
>   Or have you always known?
>   You've just hidden it away.
>   You know the truth.
>   They were nobody.
>   They were filthy junk traders...
>   who sold you off for drinking money.
>   They're dead...
>   in a poverished grave
>   in the Jakku desert.
>   You have no place in this story.
>   You come from nothing
>   you're nothing.

It's not clear why he would say this. Either he's just shooting from the hip, or he's had another Force vision of sorts and got it wrong. What's his angle in saying it? Looking for in-universe explanations.

Comment: Because he lacked the power of Force Retcon Visions.

Comment: It was true...from a certain point of view.

Comment: Well there's simply the chance that he was being a typical manipulative Darksider jerk and lying to her to try and make her vulnerable, the same way Palpatine did to Anakin...

Comment: It is quite possible that he did believe this but then Palpatine corrected him off-screen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Kylo didn't know who Rey's parents were until Palpatine told him at the beginning *The Rise of Skywalker*. Before then he was going by what he'd found out from looking in her mind from what she remembers.

> **Kylo Ren:** You remember more than you say. I’ve been in your head.
>
> <sub>*The Rise of Skywalker*</sub>

From that he did a pretty good job and he filled in the blanks with the most likely case of what happened. They may even have disguised themselves as junk traders selling her off for a drink anyway.

> **Rey:** They were nobody. - *"Rey says this after Kylo forces her to but it is mostly right, even given what we know now they were still probably nobody."*
>
> **Kylo Ren:** They were filthy junk traders, who sold you off for drinking money. - *"He knows they sold her off, he just guessed who they were and why - probably the most likely scenario."*
>   They're dead in a pauper's grave in the Jakku desert. - *"This bit could actually be true, I don't think it's ever stated."*
>   You have no place in this story; you come from nothing. You're nothing... but not to me. - *"From a certain point of view this is true and from what she knows about herself at this point it certainly is."*
>
> <sub>*The Last Jedi*</sub>

Now to be clear that Kylo was not lying to Ren but going off what he knew we have these few lines from *The Rise of Skywalker*. Firstly, Palpatine tells Kylo who Rey is, just off screen.

> **Emperor Palpatine:** The might of the Final Order will soon be ready. It will be yours if you do as I ask. Kill the girl. End the Jedi. And become what your grandfather, Vader, could not. You will rule all the galaxies as the new emperor. But beware, she is not who you think she is.
>
> **Kylo Ren:** Who is she?
>
> <sub>*The Rise of Skywalker*</sub>

And later when he confronts Rey about it he confirms that he didn't lie

> **Kylo Ren:** I pushed you in the desert because I needed to see you. I needed you to see who you are. I know the rest of your story. Rey.
>
> **Rey:** You’re lying.
>
> **Kylo Ren:** I never lied to you. Your parents were no one. They chose to be, to keep you safe.
>
> <sub>*The Rise of Skywalker*</sub>

Of course when filling in the gaps it is most likely he chose a worse option so it would be more emotive for Rey and she would be more likely to join him and the dark side.

Comment: Excellent, thorough answer.

Comment: So, Kylo Ren is the clone of Obi-Wan Kenobi...